# Need help with LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following class:

```
internal class ModuleScrap
    {
        public System.DateTime ReadTime { get; set; }
        public string ScrapReason { get; set; }
        public Int16 NetScrap { get; set; }
    }
```

I could use some help with a LINQ query that retrieves all rows between a range of dates (that's the easy part), groups on `ScrapReason` and determines the sum of `NetScrap` for each group. I don't have much experience with grouping in LINQ.

Comment: What have you tried? There's a very nice [101 LINQ samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746) page to get you started, and it isn't a complex operation.

Comment: @jon - Take a look at Jon Skeet's answer. This is why I ask a simple question like this. If I hadn't, I would have missed a great lesson on using Sum with Int16 values.

Comment: That's the kind of lesson you cannot miss -- if need be, the compiler will remind you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this, I suspect:

```
var query = from scrap in scraps
            where scrap.ReadTime >= minDate && scrap.ReadTime <= maxDate
            group scrap by scrap.ScrapReason into g
            select new { Reason = g.Key, Total = g.Sum(x => (int) x.NetScrap) };
```

Note that the `int` cast is because [`Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) isn't defined for `Int16` values. An alternative is to change the grouping:

```
var query = from scrap in scraps
            where scrap.ReadTime >= minDate && scrap.ReadTime <= maxDate
            group (int) scrap.NetScrap by scrap.ScrapReason into g
            select new { Reason = g.Key, Total = g.Sum() };
```

They'll give the same results - it's just a matter of which you prefer.

Comment: nicely done Jon, and +1 for the reference on Sum not being available for Int16, I really wasn't aware of that!